# Python os.path.realpath failed to show location

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access

I have an MS Access DB and a python script to read its data. Both MS Access and Python script are in the same folder. I created couple of lines python code to do that and code is below.

```
import os
dir_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

To make it work with MS Access, I packaged it by using pyinstaller and make it as exe file. Then go to MS Access and create macro to run it.

However, if I directly click the exe file, it works well and show me the current exe file path. If I run the macro, the path always shows as "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents". Anyone has any idea about the reason and how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're running a python script from within MS Access to find the location of that Access database? Simply using VBA within the Access database of `Left(currentdb.Name,InStrRev(currentdb.Name,"\"))` will give you the database's current folder.

Comment: Thanks @Applecore. I have other steps to let python read Access tables so have to let python get the path.

Comment: @Applecore Or rather: `CurrentProject.Path`

Comment: @Vincent If you want Python to have the path, you'll have to pass it from Access or invoke Python using Access's working directory.

Comment: @ErikA, I think both may work but without a path, how python can get the Access's location? The only condition is python script and Access are in the same folder but their parent folder maybe changed. Wish to have this fully adapted to any path change. Thanks!